# JSON to Array PHP

Tags: php, json

I have Json:

```
[{"name":"firstname","value":"wwwwww"},{"name":"lastname","value":"w"},{"name":"age","value":"99"},{"name":"sex","value":"male"}]
```

How to get array like this:

```
array(
    'firstname' => 'name',
    'lastname' => 'surname',
    'age' => '99',
    'sex' => 'male'
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
    $x=json_decode('[{"name":"firstname","value":"wwwwww"},{"name":"lastname","value":"w"},{"name":"age","value":"99"},{"name":"sex","value":"male"}]',true);
$out=array();
foreach ($x as $y){

$out[$y['name']]=$y['value'];   
}

print_r($out);
```

Live: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kaWRyt

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is the only JSON you have, let's store it in `$json` for the sake of the example:

```
$json = '[{"name":"firstname","value":"wwwwww"},{"name":"lastname","value":"w"},{"name":"age","value":"99"},{"name":"sex","value":"male"}]';
```

First, `json_decode` your JSON so we can use PHP to process it:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Then create an array to store your processed data an iterate through it, retrieving and assigned values to the array to achieve your desire structure:

```
$processed_data = array();
foreach($data as $data_field) {
    $processed_data[$data_field->name] = $data_field->value;
}
```

Here's a `var_dump` of the resulting array:

```
array(4) {
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(6) "wwwwww"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(1) "w"
  ["age"]=>
  string(2) "99"
  ["sex"]=>
  string(4) "male"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy. Just use `json_decode` & then roll through the array with `foreach` like so:

```
// JSON string as set in your example.
$string = '[{"name":"first name","value":"wwwwww"},{"name":"last name","value":"w"},{"name":"age","value":"99"},{"name":"sex","value":"male"}]';

// Use `json_decode` to decode the JSON with the `true` setting to set output to an array.
$array = json_decode($string, true);

// Now roll through the array & set the final values.
$final_values = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $final_values[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
}

// Dump the final values to check the reordering.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_values);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [first name] => wwwwww
    [last name] => w
    [age] => 99
    [sex] => male
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple loop after decoding using `json_decode()`.

```
<?php 

$json = '[{"name":"firstname","value":"wwwwww"},{"name":"lastname","value":"w"},{"name":"age","value":"99"},{"name":"sex","value":"male"}]';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$d='';
foreach($data as $item){
    $d[$item['name']] = $item['value']; 
}

print_r($data);
print_r($d);

?>
```

The first `$data` array warrants this return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => firstname
            [value] => wwwwww
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => lastname
            [value] => w
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => age
            [value] => 99
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => sex
            [value] => male
        )

)
```

While the second array (`$d`) that is created in the foreach loop warrants the return you want:

```
Array
(
    [firstname] => wwwwww
    [lastname] => w
    [age] => 99
    [sex] => male
)
```

#### Example